# Accessing parent class instance variables from child class instances

Tags: java

So right now, I have a `Preprocessor` class that generates a bunch of instance variable maps, and a `Service` class that has a `setPreprocessor(Preprocessor x)` method, so that an instance of the `Service` class is able to access the maps that the preprocessor generated.

At the moment, my `Service` class needs to call three methods in succession; for sake of simplicity, let's call them `executePhaseOne`, `executePhaseTwo`, and `executePhaseThree`. Each of these three methods instantiate/modify `Service` instance variables, some of which are pointers to the `Service` instance's `Preprocessor` object.

My code has this structure right now:

```
Preprocessor preprocessor = new Preprocessor();
preprocessor.preprocess();
Service service = new Service();
service.setPreprocessor(preprocessor);
service.executePhaseOne();
service.executePhaseTwo();
service.executePhaseThree();
```

To better organize my code, I want to put each `executePhaseXXX()` call in its own separate subclass of `Service`, and leave the common data structures for all the phases in the parent class `Service`. Then, I want to have an `execute()` method in the `Service` parent class that executes all three phases in succession:

```
class ServiceChildOne extends Service {
    public void executePhaseOne() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

class ServiceChildTwo extends Service {
    public void executePhaseTwo() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}

class ServiceChildThree extends Service {
    public void executePhaseThree() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The problem is, how do I write my `execute()` method in the `Service` parent class? I have:

```
public void execute() {
    ServiceChildOne childOne = new ServiceChildOne();
    ServiceChildTwo childTwo = new ServiceChildTwo();
    ServiceChildThree childThree = new ServiceChildThree();
    System.out.println(childOne.preprocessor); // prints null
    childOne.executePhaseOne();
    childOne.executePhaseTwo();
    childOne.executePhaseThree();
}
```

However, my `childOne`, `childTwo`, and `childThree` objects aren't able to access the `preprocessor` instance variable that lives in the parent class `Service`... How could I get past this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `protected` modifier for your `Preprocessor` instance variable of `Service`, like so:

```
public class Service {
    protected Preprocessor preprocessor;
}
```

Then each subclass of `Service` has a `this.preprocessor`.

Comment: It is already protected, yet it is still null. See edit in original post, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `preprocessor` should be `protected` or `public` to be able to have an access from the child.
You can read about modifiers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

**UPDATE**

```
new ServiceChildOne(new Preprocessor());
.....

class ServiceChildOne extends Service {

    public ServiceChildOne(Preprocessor preprocessor) {
       super.preprocessor = preprocessor;
    }

    public void executePhaseOne() {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: It is already `protected`, yet it is still null. See edit in original post, please.

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up though: I need to be able to access _all_ of the instance variables that live in the `Service` parent class, not just the preprocessor. Short of passing them all into the constructor to the subclass, is there any other way I could obtain this functionality? Some way of instantiating the subclass instances, perhaps? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could provide some method like `getPreprocessorInstance()` in your `Service` class that returns `Preprocessor` instance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is that you have not one, but four different instances of `Service` - each of which has its own uninitialized copy of the base class variables.

The only solutions I can think of at the moment are, first, the rather poor design of making your Service member variables static - which, in effect, means you can only have one version of Service at a time.  A better solution, to my mind, would be to **not** make the processing phases subclasses, but instead make them independent classes that take an instance of `Service` as a parameter.

EDIT:
For a quick example, the `Service` class could look like:

```
class Service
{
    public Service() { ... }
    public Preprocessor getPreprocessor() { ... }
    public void setPreprocessor(Preprocessor preprocessor { ... }
    public Type2 getVariable2() { ... }
    public void setVariable2(Type2 variable2) { ... }
        ...
}
```

and the phase classes could look something like:

```
class ServicePhaseOne
{
    private Service m_dataHost;

    public ServicePhaseOne(Service dataHost)
    {
        m_dataHost = dataHost;
    }

    public void executePhaseOne()
    {
        // Do phase 1 stuff
    }
}
```

... and so on for phase 2 and phase 3.

The execute() method would then look like:

```
public void execute()
{
    ServicePhaseOne phaseOne = new ServicePhaseOne(this);
    ServicePhaseTwo phaseTwo = new ServicePhaseTwo(this);
    ServicePhaseThree phaseThree = new ServicePhaseThree(this);
    phaseOne .executePhaseOne();
    phaseTwo .executePhaseTwo();
    phaseThree .executePhaseThree();
}
```